# How to get series of data using user input in Java

Tags: java, console, user-input

I am trying to get series of user input and from them I need to get this kind of output, I tried various methods but didn't work.

```
Day      Sales
Sunday   $ 0.00
Monday   $ 4,300.76
Tuesday  $ 276.92
Wednesday$ 15,976.43
Thursday $ 0.00
Friday   $ 49,764.67
Saturday $ 250.00
-----------
Total Sales: $ 70,568.78
Average sale value: $2,367.92
Commission on Sales: $7,551.19 ***
```

I am trying using this, But it gives me errors and I don't have idea to get that kind of output. And also I used list but how can I separate the values?

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Day of Sale (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.): ");
        String text = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Sale Amount: ");
        int a  = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine(), 7);
        System.out.println("Are you finished entering sales? (Y/N)");

        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println(a);
        if (br.readLine().startsWith("y"))
        {
        } else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    br.close();
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you handle the `IOException` that the `BufferedReader` can produce? Because the `readLine` method got `throws IOException` so you need to handle that. P.S: I would recommend to use the `Scanner` instead

Comment: *It gives me errors* is not a working problem description. See [mcve]. Beyond that: go about one problem after the other. And *first* use a search engine and see what others already asked before.

Comment: On what criteria you are calculating commission ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** - Introduce object which will hold data, and add object's to List. To display, iterate thru List.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 List<Entry> collectedData = new ArratList<>();

    do
    {
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        System.out.println("Enter Day of Sale (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.): ");
        entry.dayName = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Sale Amount: ");
        entry.value  = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine(), 7);
        collectedData.add(entry);
        System.out.println("Are you finished entering sales? (Y/N)");

        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println(a);
        if (br.readLine().startsWith("y"))
        {
        } else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

for(entry : collectedData) {
    System.out.println(entry.dayName + ": " + entry.value);
}

public class Entry {
    String dayName;
    Integer value;
}
```